# How to get data from json thats been returned from an ajax call?

Tags: jquery, ajax, json

this will post a string to the controller

```
        var jsonObject = new Object();
        jsonObject.url = bankAccountUrl;
        var dataobject = JSON.stringify(jsonObject);

        // Post to controller
        $.ajax({
            url: "/Home/SwitchAccounts/",
            type: "POST",
            contentType: 'application/json',
            data: dataobject,
            success: function (returnedJson) {
                alert(returnedJson.type.toString());
                var ob = JSON.parse(returnedJson);
                //loop though ob and populate dropdown
            }
        });
```

controller: - this is a list of a list of objects

```
//Global variable
public static List<List<BankTransaction>> transactions = new List<List<BankTransaction>>();
```

This is the method that will select one of the lists of objects and return it

```
public JsonResult SwitchAccounts(BankAccounts bankAccount)
    {
        bankAccountUrl = bankAccount.url;
        int count = 0;
        string error = "error";

        foreach (var transaction in transactions)
        {
            foreach (var account in transaction)
            {
                if (bankAccountUrl == account.bank_account)
                {
                    var json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(transactions[count]);
                    return Json(new { json }, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
                }
                break; 
            }
            count++;
        }

        // return errror
        return Json(new { error }, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
    }
```

The problem is with the ajax call, everything else works fine. 
I would like to populate a dropdown menu based on what is in the list being returned e.g the list of objects will have a 'name' but i cannot get it to parse the json and get the name from the lists? 
any ideas? or do i need to provide more info :)

Comment: What is the response you're getting? Is it valid JSON? Can you show the response in the question please?

Comment: `console.log(returnedJson)` returns...? I think you should use `return Json(json, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet)` instead of `return Json(new { json }, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);`